# Data recovery on flash drive showing incorrect size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, usb-storage, dd

I have a Kingston 32gb USB 3.0 flash drive that I need to recover data from. The problem is that the drive is now showing as 32.5kb of raw storage in Ubuntu (using gparted) and Windows is not registering it at all.

My real problem is that I need to fix the sizing issue without destroying any of the data that may be still there.

From what I understand the dd utility on Ubuntu ignores partitions and such so it should copy the entire drive but attempting to clone it to a image file via `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=kingstonclone.img conv=noerror,sync` only copies 32.5kb. Also tried ddrescue with similar results.

Additional info:

Results of fdisk -l on Ubuntu

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 0 MB, 33280 bytes
1 heads, 1 sectors/track, 65 cylinders, total 65 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
identifier: 0xbbbab9b8

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```